# Show if propel successfully deleted related data

Tags: php, sql, propel

I have something like this

```
    $table = TableQuery::create()
     ->findOneByTableId(1);
    foreach($table->getSomeTables() as $item) { // SomeTable is a table linked with foreign-key
     $table->removeSomeTable($item);
    }
    if($table->save()) {
     echo "success";
    }else {
     echo "fail";
    }
```

The problem here is that despite the $table having someTablesScheduledForDeletion and successfully removing it from database when calling method save(), save still returns 0, as if "0 records were changed", though some records are actually deleted.
The same thing goes if I attach more things in a similar way as I did with someTables

What I want to achieve with this is to just get information if these elements were successfully removed

Comment: What version of MySql are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You should just call `->delete()` on `$item`, then you can use `->isDeleted()` as intended.

For example:

```
$table = TableQuery::create()->findOneByTableId(1);
$deleted = 0;
foreach ($table->getSomeTables() as $item) {
    $item->delete();
    if ($item->isDeleted()) {
        $deleted++;
    }
}
if ($deleted > 0) {
    echo "Rows deleted.";
} else {
    echo "No rows deleted.";
}
```

Comment: That could possibly work, I'll keep that solution in mind in the future. I solved the issue back then with overwriting save in model:
        $save = false;
        if(count($this->getSomeTables()) > 0 || $this->getSomeTablesScheduledForDeletion) $save = true;
         foreach ($this->getSomeTables() as $key => $table) {
            if($table->isModified() && !$table->save()) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return (parent::save($con) || $save) ? true : false

Sorry for the format, but not sure how to do it lol

Answer (score -1):

Issuing another query may be useful. Is there some reason to avoid this?

Comment: Is there any reason a re-query would not meet your needs?

Comment: I have multiple relations, for example I might need to use 5 different removeSomeTable